What is the part between 2 knuckles called in everyday English?
I am teaching my daughter to hold a pencil.

(Source)
Wiki How says

Rest your middle finger on the pen. Bring your middle finger down,
underneath the pen. Your middle finger is the third finger to grip the
pen, except only the upper half of the tip contacts the pen.

I am explaining to my daughter how to rest her pencil on the middle finger. She must not rest the pencil on the knuckle, but rest it on the soft part between the tip and the first knuckle of the middle finger.
Wiki how says "Rest your middle finger on the pen", then it is not so clear because what if the pen rest on the knuckle of the middle finger?

(Source)
I might say "rest the top of the pencil on the phalanx not the knuckle".
Do we have a common word for phalanx in everyday English?
Or
What is the part between 2 knuckles called in everyday English?

I've been using English for 70 years, and until now it's never occurred to me that some people use "knuckle" for the second & third finger joints - to me, knuckles are only the first joint, between the finger and the hand proper. With that level of imprecision passing unnoticed for so long, I seriously doubt there will be a special term for the "straight" bits in fingers. We don't always need words for things it's so easy to point to. In the real world you don't really describe / explain in words how to hold a pen, use chopsticks, snap your fingers, or whatever etc. You show.

Show.  Don't Tell

@JamesK - exactly. With small children (i.e. at the age they are learning to hold a pencil) we use a combination of showing and saying ('hold it like this' - like I am holding my pencil) and (possibly) gently manipulating their fingers around the pencil. Believe me, Tom, if you give them a lecture involving phalanxes they won't understand it and you will just put them off drawing and writing for life!!! I say that to you very seriously, based on my experience both as a parent, and, (believe me!) as a child before that.

@FumbleFingers - I have been using English for a comparable length of time, and I supposed, without really thinking about it, that the fingers have three joints each, and the thumbs two, and that some folks call 'em all 'knuckles' and some restrict that to the first ones, where the digits join the hands. When I was a lad, a 'knuckle sandwich' was a school break time snack you didn't want to be offered.

I am speechless. Parenting doesn't always involve verbal instructions. Children learn by imitation because their brains are not fully developed yet and their level of maturity and attention span is, naturally, limited. Very young children imitate, and mimic what their elders and peers say and do.  Tell your daughter "Hold the pencil like this“ that is infinitely more useful for her to hear and learn rather than learning the name for a specific part of the body.

Simply imagine you had never seen a pencil and had never seen anyone write something down, we're on our phones and computers all day so this scenario won't be too far in the future! Anyway, imagine reading that instruction without a picture as a reference. No picture and no one physically showing how to hold a pencil, would you be able to hold that pencil in that exact way? Now pretend you are five/six years old,  would you not instinctively grab the pencil in your fist and scribble?

@Mari-LouA - Even when older, showing and doing often work better. When I was aged 12, my parents had the (very) misguided idea that I might benefit from the free violin lessons my school was offering. You wouldn't believe the trouble I had holding the bow properly! Or maybe you would. Eventually the teacher, a nice old boy, got hold of my hand and gently bent the fingers (and thumb!) in the right manner. Much screeching ensued. Things did not get much better and the project was abandoned by mutual consent.

@Mari-LouA - already university tutors in the UK are finding that new students very often have extremely poor handwriting skills, and their handwritten efforts can be illegible. Cambridge was thinking of scrapping handwritten examinations.

Children are not taught cursive, get them to write in block capital letters and they cope but joined up writing? It's the same story in Italy. Cambridge is pushing for computer-based exams worldwide for English language exams. I can only manage how difficult an examiner must find deciphering many, if not most,  candidates' handwriting.

@Mari-LouA - my father told me he had to learn something called 'Copperplate', and writing pages of it was given as a punishment for misbehaviour (England, 1930s)

Wiki is incorrect to say "Rest your middle finger on the pen." You rest the pen there, not the finger on the pen.

No one rests their finger on a pencil when writing. They hold the pencil or pen between fingers; the thumb, index and middle finger.

@Lambie - Lamy (no relation, I trust?) have a helpful guide to holding a pen

"Hold the pen ergotherapeutically, child."

Edit
Not everything should go through a description like that.  Here we should just show.  However, if we must write, then simple words would do instead of medical terms used by the professionals.  We can just say section: rest your pencil on the last section of your middle finger.

Pencils and pens involve the tips of the fingers, more than the segments...

Thanks, @Lambie.  Agreed.  The gripping involves more of the zones near the tips (of thumb and index finger) than the segment (of middle finger) which is more for the pencil to rest on.  This further shows how much more logical it is to teach by showing rather than describing.

The point is there is no "resting". If you have a lounge chair and push back, a platform pops out of the chair and you can stretch out your legs on it. That would be resting your legs on something.

Although all the other answers are right, that there are better ways to teach this skill, I feel like it's worth answering the question itself:
No, there's no common word for the space between knuckles. "Phalanx" is a useful word, but it's not common knowledge. (I've heard the plural, "phalanges," far more often, usually as a playful way of talking about fingers and toes, because it's a silly-sounding word to say.)
Sometimes I've heard the word "knuckle" used to mean phalanx, a segment of finger, but this would technically be a mis-usage.
The simplest and most accessible way to describe this would probably just be "the part of the finger between these two knuckles." (In teaching violin bow hold to young children, I didn't even use words as technical as "knuckle": "Feel these two big, bony bumps in your finger? And this dip in between them? Let the bow rest in that dip between the two bumps.")

Look at Laurel's answer to the actual question, even though the actual question is a bomb. :)

Segment
It's not the technical term, but it's readily understood. Make sure you're clear that you're referring to a part of the finger, since "segment" alone is quite generic; even a clock might have segments.
The top segment is the fingertip, the bottom segment is attached to the palm and the middle segment is the one in between.
Here's an example from Drawing and Coloring Hands:

Fingers grow slightly skinnier towards the tip, and are broken into three segments. The top segment has a rounded tip as the finger ends.

Kansas Orthopaedic Center has another example (in an article about hand exercises):


Flexion: Movement of the last two segments of the finger towards the base of the finger.
Extension: Movement of the last two segments of the finger away from the base of the finger.



Yes, the parts between knuckles (two on every finger) and the three parts a finger divides into are segments. But in everyday speech, those are not referred to when describing gripping or grasping a pen or pencil.


I am explaining to my daughter how to rest her pencil on the middle finger. She must not rest the pencil on the knuckle, but rest it on the soft part between the tip and the first knuckle of the middle finger.

I have noticed that many teachers and parents place great importance on how a child holds a pencil.
Handwriting can be improved if proper guidance is given.
The grasp depicted in OP's picture is called "the tripod grasp". It is more important to know what the grasp is called.

Ref. cstacademy.com.
A  dynamic tripod grasp utilizes the tips of the child’s fingers on the writing utensil and they also hold the utensil more at an angle than vertical. Wrist movements are considered dynamic when the child moves them back and forth without any full arm movement. The dynamic tripod grasp has traditionally been considered the preferred grip for writing speed, control and form.


Ref. https://otperspective.com/tripod-grasp-fine-motor/



There ought to be no need to describe that part of the hand so specifically.
If you instructed as follows:

Pinch the pen between your thumb and index finger.
Let the pen rest on your middle finger for support.

'Pinching' means to grip with the ends of the finger and thumb, so this verb negates the need to describe which part of the fingers to use. When following this instruction with the two stated digits, the pen will rest quite naturally on the correct part of the middle finger.

Hm, as a teacher I'd carefully choose words with connotations of relaxation rather than tension, like "pinch." As a violin teacher I avoid phrases like "grip the bow" and instead do things like #2 here, "let the bow sit on this finger like this." I might teach the pen hold with some of the same strategies I use for the bow, like having the student "tap" their fingertip against the pen, then rest it there—posture through motion rather than stasis.

I dunno, pinching for holding a pen or pencil? Grasp or gripping a pen or pencil.

@lambie 'grasp' means hold but not specifically with just two fingers. You would say someone who held your hand with their entire hand had a good grasp. I agree it's a perfectly suitable word to describe holding a pen or pencil, but the point of my answer was to use a word that describes how it is held.

pinch is to squeeze between thumb and forefinger. Like a pimple. Or when you want to tease or even hurt someone.

@lambie or a pinch of salt. Yeah you got to really squeeze that.

SHOW AND TELL

What is a correct pencil grip called?
You may see pencil grip and pencil grasp used interchangeably. However, for the purpose of this post, I am referring to the way the
child actually holds the pencil as “pencil grasp”. A pencil grip
would be an additional tool used on the pencil to help promote
efficient grasp. I'll address pencil grips specifically as one of the
tips below.
There are a few types of functional grasps. It's important to remember
that children are still developing their grasp until age 5 and older.
A 3-year-old is not going to be developmentally ready for these types
of grasps.
The two types of efficient or functional pencil grasps are a dynamic
tripod (3-finger grasp), and a dynamic quadrupod grasp (4-finger
grasp).

See the pictures here
Here is one picture:




Downvoting this is simply silly.
